# How do I find all files above a certain size while ignoring certain directories (using a bash script)

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

so I'm trying to use bash to find all files above 500MB.  I have been able to accomplish this using `find ~ size +500M`.
However, the output contains a lot of python library files that aren't relevant to my search.  So how do I adjust this command (using bash or grep or awk) so that it excludes certain directories (for example /webapps/lib/python2.7/)  Thanks for the help in advance, everyone.

Comment: Why bother with `awk`? `find` has all the functionality needed. Also, awk is not bash, so if you wanted an awk script, it would *not* be a bash script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -path /webapps/lib/python2.7 -prune -o -size +500M
```

Comment: Almost right, but you should add an explicit `-print` action on the end.

Comment: hmm this causes there to be no results, even though I know there are 500M+ size files elsewhere.  Any idea as to why?

Comment: `find .` is starting from the current directory.  If not, substitute the right starting directory. Also if excluded paths are under current directory prefix it with `./`  Also, M suffix might not be standard, you may need +512000k

Comment: This ended up saving me a bunch of time and disk hits with find-grep ala `find . \( -name .svn -o -name .git -o -size +1M \) -prune -o -exec grep -F searchstring {} +`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `path` with negation. For example, the following command will exclude results whose path start with "~/path1" or "~/path2"

```
find ~ size +500M ! -path "~/path1/*" ! -path "~/path2/*"
```

Comment: hm this doesn't seem to be working.  For the specific file path I mentioned, would I need escape characters or anything?

Comment: You might have to add a star to the path to specify exclude results starting with some path. I have updated the answer